# Too many listeners and slow $compile, need performance tips or something between two-way binding and one-time binding

Tags: angularjs, performance

Sorry, I don't have a live example, I'm looking for performance advice.

I've finally hit my first performance problem with angular, I have a pretty complex UI and in it, I have a directive with about 3 nested repeats that use directives, in every level the directive uses `scope: true` and using `bindToController` syntax.

The data source is not that big, but every repeat ends up being between 30-100 watchers (I'm using [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/kentcdodds/31c90402750572107922) to count the watchers)

I'm calling `$compile` on the top directive and it takes way over a second (!) to show the HTML (it ends up having a few hundred listeners), `ng-if` and `ng-class` and other custom directives, it quickly adds up.

I've added one-time bindings wherever I could, but I'm still at way over a 1000 in total and I guess that can slow things down?

I've ran CPU profilers in different browsers, drilled as deep as possible and I never saw my code taking up and significant time, all I see it jquery/angular taking a long long time, but none of the functions inside show any significant *self time*.

[image: profiler]

If I open that 800ms `elemData.handle`, all I see is angular's `$scope.eval`, `compileDirectives` and a bunch of other angular stuff in a deep tree.

Could using `scope: true` be the culprit? Would complex directives perform better if they use an isolate scopes?

Maybe there are advanced methods I don't know to use one-time bindings? Or something between two-way and one-way?

EDIT: for posterity, this is what happened: I managed to replace my isolate scope directives on the inner-most `ng-repeat` level with simple `ng-includes`, the functionality is the same, but execution time is 1/1000. I don't think I'll ever really know why the difference was so huge, I never had many items in the `ng-repeat`, but the code now runs in 1ms :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `$destroy` events to clean up event watchers
2. Use one-way-binding everywhere what you can't change manually (`ng-repeat`, `ng-options`)
3. In templates try to avoid functions that will return value. Simple assignment not needed to be compiled but function will run each `$digest` (`ng-if="ctrl.isDataLiading()"` slower then `ng-if="ctrl.isDataLoaded"`)
4. In list items with a lot of `ng-repeat` avoid filters that will recount and run collection watchers on arrays that is taking great portion of performance - instead use `ng-if` to remove filtered items

When I was implementing tree structure that can be like expanded to see child nodes (list with + option) I struggled with such problem. Above approach made functionality better but speed did not rise a lot.

In common words all my answer means: **angular populates too many watchers, get rid of them**

Comment: When I just started having performance problems, I did all that (1-3) and managed to eliminate about a third of the watchers (good suggestions btw). I wish I could turn more things into one way binding and somehow "trigger" its change manually, because a lot of things don't really need to be bound in real-time. Number #4 is an interesting point and I'll try to find hot spots where I might be doing that. Thanks

Comment: jQuery always had memory leak problems if you did not clean removed elements links or off their events

Comment: In real you can, the secret is to compile template before it was actually used - create your html with angular.element, take its content and put in to $templateCache. So you will never need to use ng-repeat static or ng-options on static code

Comment: huh. I managed to overlook the timeline tool in chrome during all my investigations and it shows a second of nested `parse HTML` commands from jquery `buildFragment`. So pre-computing templates seems like the ultimate solution for these problems. But doesn't that mean that I will lose all the advantages of data-binding? How the hell do I find the place where it would matter most?

Comment: You can pre-compile only part of html you need. Choose wisely.

Comment: went from directive to ng-include and execution time went down to 1ms. I don't know what angular was doing during those 1000ms before

Comment: Compiling obviously :D and with ng-include compiling of page and included template became separated and asynchronous

Comment: As well as escaping of creation of directives scope and creating another ton of watchers

Comment: But it's such a huge difference (1ms to 1000ms), it's not like I had hundreds of items, I had under 10 items. It's all super complex with dozens of `ng-if`s and watches, but they still exist in the `ng-include` version. How can passing parameters to an isolate scope 10 times * 5 parameters create such a slow-down (also the timeline in chrome said `parse Html`, not anything from angular itself). Oh well, I guess I shouldn't complain.

Comment: Just use react buddy :)